# Redirect within a class based view

Tags: django

I'm working with a FormView. In order to access the page, the user has to pass a certain test. Otherwise, they'll be logged out and redirected. Where within this CBV is the best place to put the redirect logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Seriously ? without any code example it's hard to suggest some answer ? POST THE CODE and w'll try to help you.

Comment: Rvector, there are standard functions within a FormView. Just wondering where to put the logic. I was able to figure it out though. Its the dispatch function